# Problem implementing BFS for my graph data struct

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is design of my graph data structure which i've developed from scratch. Now to implement BFS i am thinking to use some part of STL to levitate more burden.
[image: Here is]

I am using algorithm from Cormen's book .For some portion of algorithms like
color[u] , distance[u] etc , i am thinking to use map. but i am unable to decided whether
i should use map like >> `std::map<node<T>*, Node_struct_data_like_color_etc>` or
`std::map<data_type_which_node_contains, Node_struct_data_like_color_etc>`

Also, Above map will have to fit with other part of algo like
`for(all_adjacent_vertex_v_of_u)` etc

I am sorry that my question might would look vague but couldn't explain more better than this.

Comment: What's preventing you from storing data like color, etc. in a node? I think it would be logical if properties like color would be associated with nodes.

Comment: hmm.. but i don't want to edit the graph struct rather than just adding BFS functionality

Comment: Why not? And if your nodes don't store node properties such as color, what do they store?

Comment: @aib : think this will force me edit other functions also which i've already implemented which i really don't want. tell me is my idea of using map is bogus?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Well, no. As I've stated in my answer it's an approach BGL uses. But I don't understand, aren't you already using pointers, `node<T>*`? What will happen if you add an extra field to `node`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i was trying to do something similar. The mistake i did was i didn't define the
function object to sort the elements of the `map` when i stored the pointer to the node as index type. So you should consider this when you design your BFS when keeping the color/other properties as value_type in the map with node pointers as the index type.

so the map that you are planning to implement should look something like this

```
std::map<Node_t*,NodeProperty_t*,SortNode>

struct SortNode{
operator()(Node_t*,Node_t*){
//...
}
}
```

Comment: so you prefer the design which you have told rather than `std::map<data_type_which_node_contains, Node_struct_data_like_color_etc>`

Comment: yes... it is much similar to your `std::map<node<T>*, Node_struct_data_like_color_etc> ` with a SortNode argument. It is a good idea to keep only the pointer to the `Node` rather than the `Node` itself

Answer (score 1):

I have this simple bfs written if it helps

```
//simple bfs assuming graph is of the form vecotr<int> g
int q[20000];
int vis[20000];

void bfs( int v_ )
{
    int top = 0;
    memset(vis, 0, sizeof(vis));
    vis[v_] = 1;
    q[top++]=v_;
    while( top )
    {
        int v = q[--top];
        for( vector<int>::iterator it = g[v].begin(); it!= g[v].end(); ++it )
        {
            int u = *it;
            if( !vis[u] )
            {
                q[top++]=u;
                vis[u] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what part excatly do you need help..is it the graph representation, in that case you can have a class named node which contains a vector<node> adjacents and other attributes you want like color etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/) for inspiration, or even just use it.

Note that it supports both property maps (like the first map you suggested) and custom node classes (what @Grigory Javadyan and I suggest).